# Rebuilding a Site: How to Show Several Category Posts in Woo Framework Theme?

Tags: categories, archives, blog, framework

I am having a hard time managing a big site with 2000+ pages.

Right now, I am restructuring the site architecture. So, for example, if there are categories like x, y, z... I want to put them under "A."

This A can be a page or a blog, but it should have a pagination (should update dynamically whenever a new post is added under x, y, z category).

Similarly, I want to put several other categories in "B."

I have tried various plugins, like posts to page, posts for page... and even List Categories with Pagination plugin. What I am looking for is another archive/blog page that lists the posts from defined categories.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the template-blog.php file, if it helps.

```
   <?php
 /**
  * Template Name: Blog
  *
  * The blog page template displays the "blog-style" template on a sub-page. 
  *
  * @package WooFramework
  * @subpackage Template
  */

  get_header();
  global $woo_options;
 ?>      
<!-- #content Starts -->
<?php woo_content_before(); ?>


<div id="content" class="col-full">

    <div id="main-sidebar-container">    

        <!-- #main Starts -->
        <?php woo_main_before(); ?>


        <section id="main" class="col-left">

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'blog' ); ?>

        </section><!-- /#main -->
        <?php woo_main_after(); ?>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div><!-- /#main-sidebar-container -->         

    <?php get_sidebar( 'alt' ); ?>       

</div><!-- /#content -->
<?php woo_content_after(); ?>

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Edit:** Going through Codex.WordPress, I see that there is a possibility:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```

I wonder how to incorporate this code into my blog file.

Edit 2: Modified it this way, still doesn't work. Check edit 3.

Edit 3: Here is the loop-blog.php template.

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop - Blog
 *
 * This is the loop file used on the "Blog" page template.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
global $more; $more = 0; 

woo_loop_before();

// Fix for the WordPress 3.0 "paged" bug.
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
$paged = intval( $paged );

$query_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post', 
                'paged' => $paged
            );

$query_args = apply_filters( 'woo_blog_template_query_args', $query_args ); // Do not     remove. Used to exclude categories from displaying here.

remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'woo_exclude_categories_homepage', 10 );

query_posts( $query_args );

if ( have_posts() ) { $count = 0;
?>

<div class="fix"></div>

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $count++;

    woo_get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );

} // End WHILE Loop
} else {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'noposts' );
} // End IF Statement

woo_loop_after();

woo_pagenav();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) { $count = 0;
    while ($query->have_posts()) { the_post(); $count++;
```

Use this:

```
 if ($query->have_posts()) { $count = 0;
    while ($query->have_posts()) { $query->the_post(); $count++;
```

Comment: I have updated the files (some lines were missing). Even after messing with the file, adding the code you have mentioned I am not able to get it to work. Appreciate if you can look at it again.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice the `WooFramework` reference in your code (even though it is very obvious). Edit the post one more time, but add Woo Framework into the title to the question to (perhaps) `Show Several Category Posts in Woo Framework Theme` to attract people who know the Woo Framework. HTH